# I want to put a video as a desktop background how to do it?

Tags: desktop-environments

I want to put cool videos as background on my ubuntu desktop so I wondered that if there is an app or program that can do this, and how I do this, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this site for instructions about setting up a video as a wall paper:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/dreamscene-for-ubuntu-ta-very-much/